# Best practices for ArangoDB compaction on-demand for file space reclamation

Tags: database-administration, arangodb

Part of my evaluation of ArangoDB involves importing a few CSV files of over 1M rows into a staging area, then deleting the resulting collections or databases.  I will need to do this repeatedly for the production processes I envision.

I understand the the ArangoDB service invokes compaction periodically per this page:

https://github.com/arangodb/docs/blob/2c842774b457114c571abdaa8391a038715d1458/3.3/administration-configuration-compaction.md

After deleting a database, I waited over 24 hours and no disk space has been reclaimed, so I'm not sure this automated process is working.

I'd like answers to these questions:

1. What are the default values for the automatic compaction parameters shown in the link above?
2. Other than observing a change in file space, how do I know that a compaction worked?  Is the a log file or other place that would indicate this?
3. How can I execute a compaction on-demand?  All the references I found that discussed such a feature indicated that it was not possible, but they were from several years ago and I'm hoping this feature has been added.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The `GET` route `/_api/collection/{collection-name}/figures` contains a sub-attribute `compactionStatus` in the attribute `figures` with `time` and `message` of the last compaction for debugging purposes. There is also some other information in the response that you might be interested in. See if `doCompact` is set to true at all.
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/75481b429979ef3b253effcba21d9232434db55e/Documentation/DocuBlocks/Rest/Collections/JSA_get_api_collection_figures.md

You can run `arangod --help-compaction` to see the startup options for compaction including the default values. This information is also available in the source file used in the 3.4 docs:
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/3.4/Documentation/Examples/arangod.json#L467-L592

The `PUT` route `/_api/collection/{collection-name}/rotate`, quoting the documentation directly:

> Rotates the journal of a collection. The current journal of the
> collection will be closed and made a read-only datafile. The purpose
> of the rotate method is to make the data in the file available for
> compaction (compaction is only performed for read-only datafiles, and
> not for journals)
>
> Saving new data in the collection subsequently will create a new journal file automatically if there is no current journal.

https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/3.3/Documentation/DocuBlocks/Rest/Collections/JSF_put_api_collection_rotate.md